# How to test console command output when terminal widths differ?

Tags: console, phpunit, symfony

I'm playing with the console component of Symfony and I'm facing an issue when it comes to testing.

I have a command that can move some files and display messages depending on the actions performed. I'm using SymfonyStyle to format my output.

I'm using the CommandTester to test my command but if I'm able to test whether the command did something or not, I can't find a efficient way to test its output.

Here is what I'm trying to do :

```
<?php
public function testIgnoreSamples()
{
    $container = $this->application->getContainer();

    $container['config'] = [
        'source_directory' => vfsStream::url('Episodes/From'),
        'target_directory' => vfsStream::url('Episodes/To'),
        'ignore_if_nuked' => false,
        'delete_nuked' => false,
        'search_subtitles' => false,
        'prefer_move_over_copy' => false
    ];

    copy(
        __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'Fixtures/breakdance.mp4',
        vfsStream::url('Episodes/From/sample-angie.tribeca.s01e07.720p.hdtv.x264-killers.mkv')
    );

    $commandTester = new CommandTester($this->application->find('episodes:move'));
    $commandTester->execute([]);

    $this->assertContains('because it\'s a sample', $commandTester->getDisplay());
    $this->assertEquals([], vfsStream::inspect(new vfsStreamStructureVisitor())->getStructure()['Episodes']['To'], 'Target directory is empty');
}
```

The issue here is that depending on the console size, my output can be displayed on one or two lines, which makes it hard to write tests that can be executed in different environment.

For example in my environment it's displayed like this :

[image: output in my computer]

and in travis like this :

[image: output on travis]

which brakes the tests.

Do you know if the component provides a workaround for this case?

Comment: You may consider retitling this question "How to test console command output when terminal widths differ?", because you in fact understand how to test one in the first place.

Comment: Hi Jonag. Did @cilefen 's answer actually answer your question? Or do you still need help?

Comment: @cilefen's answer implies modifying the behaviour of the command, so I'm still looking for a better solution if someone has an idea..

Comment: You shouldn't test output of command, test class method that's invoked by your command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured how to fix the terminal size for the tests.

Starting in v3.2, symfony/console allows us to fix the terminal size, which is used by the SymfonyStyle to build the output.

Just call `putenv('COLUMNS=80')` before executing a command to fix its terminal size.

My test is now :

```
public function testIgnoreSamples()
{
    $container = $this->application->getContainer();

    $container['config'] = [
        'source_directory' => vfsStream::url('Episodes/From'),
        'target_directory' => vfsStream::url('Episodes/To'),
        'ignore_if_nuked' => false,
        'delete_nuked' => false,
        'search_subtitles' => false,
        'prefer_move_over_copy' => false
    ];

    copy(
        __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'Fixtures/breakdance.mp4',
        vfsStream::url('Episodes/From/sample-angie.tribeca.s01e07.720p.hdtv.x264-killers.mkv')
    );

    putenv('COLUMNS=80');
    $commandTester = new CommandTester($this->application->find('episodes:move'));
    $commandTester->execute([]);

    $expected = <<<'EXPECTED'
! [NOTE] File sample-angie.tribeca.s01e07.720p.hdtv.x264-killers.mkv  ignored   
!        because it's a sample  
EXPECTED;


    $this->assertContains($expected, $commandTester->getDisplay());
    $this->assertEquals([], vfsStream::inspect(new vfsStreamStructureVisitor())->getStructure()['Episodes']['To'], 'Target directory is empty');
}
```

and the tests are green in travis and in my local environment :).

Answer (score 0):

Use the wordwrap function to constrain all output to 75 or so columns.

```
$output->writeln(wordwrap($long_string));
```

Comment: Yes but I'm okay with the output being displayed in one line if the terminal size allows it ...